# Using variable in a ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I just want to use a variable from outside of the function, but I am not sure what I have to do for that...

Is `var myRequest = a;` line enough to use this variable in the function?

Because I saw such an example: `var myRequest = e.which;`

I am asking this because I did not get a succesful result for my request.

I am think that it is not working as I expected because `ajaxFunction(3)` working diffirent than writing `send.php?goto=3` into address bar of my browser.

You can see the following codes:

```
function ajaxFunction(a)
{
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "send.php?goto=" + a, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post more details, like how this would relate to your ajax call?

Comment: @JimSchubert I provide some more information about the ajax call. It is not working.

Comment: How do you determine that it is "not working"?

Comment: And how do you call `ajaxFunction` and what do you actually want to do? You did not explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: @FelixKling I am sure because send.php?goto=3 working well manually but ajaxFunction(3) is not.

Comment: What do you mean by *because `send.php?goto=3` working well*? Do you mean hardcoding the URL in the ajax call or putting it into the browser's address bar or what? Please explain yourself better, otherwise it's very difficult for us to help you. When you go the network tab in the browser's developer tools, do you see an ajax call happening?

Comment: @FelixKling I checked, it is happening with result of 304 in the browser's developer tools. What does it mean?

Comment: When you type `send.php?goto=3` into the address bar of the browser, then the browser is going to load that page. Ajax is specifically for *not* redirecting the browser to the new location. You don't have any event handlers attached to the request object, so you won't be notified about whether the call was successful or not. `304` means "Not modified": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection. I recommend that you read first a bit more about Ajax and learn how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable outside a function you have to use a global scope variable, example (using jQuery ajax)

```
var globalA = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var localA1 = null;
    $.ajax({
       "url":"http://someurl.com/",
       "type":"POST",
       "dataType":"json",
       "success":function(incomingData){
           var localA2 = incomingData //localA2 only useable inside this function
           localA1 = incomingData; //localA1 being set here still can only be used here as code within the "ready" function has already been executed and will see it as null
           globalA = incomingData; //Now any further code should use globalA as it now contains useable data
           doSomethingWithData();
       },
       "error":function(xhr,msg) {
           alert("Ajax Error:"+msg);
       }
    });
    alert(localA1); //Will give alertbox with null in it as localA1 has not been set.
});

function doSometingWithData() {
    alert(globalA); //You can now use the data in whatever function makes reference to globalA
}
```

Of course in this example you could have just passed the data straight to `doSomethingWithData()` and processed it there.

Comment: I think you have the asynchronous nature of `$.ajax` confused with a *synchronous* call in your example code.  The `alert` at the end of the ready function doesn't contain data because it executes immediately after the ajax call is sent, and not because of global variables. In other words, you're showing `$.ajax` may not complete before the alert (because it's async). Your example is correct that you'd need a global variable outside of the ready function's closure context to call from within `doSomethingWithData`, unless of course you pass `globalA` as a parameter to that function.

Comment: As an example, you can pass `"async" : false` as an option and your alert will contain data.

Comment: I didn't mean to make it sound like I thought you were wrong. My point was related to context scope. For instance, if you move the `doSomethingWithData` from the global context to the `.ready()` function, you can call `alert(localA1);` within `doSomethingWithData` and avoid global variables altogether.  My previous comment should have begun "I think you might confuse readers...". I think your point is very valid in that callbacks should be defined properly, which can almost always be done without globals (hence 'and not because of global variables' remark).

Comment: Also, for whatever reason I didn't see the comment next to setting the local variable within the callback when I first commented. I apologize for the redundancy in the first part of that comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the jQuery `$.globalEval` for instantiating a variable globally inside of your AJAX success function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "send.php",
  success: function (data) {
    $.getScript("somescript.js", function(data) {
      $.globalEval("var something = new Whatever;");
    });
});
```

The $.getScript portion is a helpful little snippet if you find you need to load an external JS file in your ajax call, and make its assets globally available.  You can then use `$.globalEval` to instantiate a variable inside of your AJAX function.

[Documentation for $.globalEval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/)

[Documentation for jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: That's unnecessary and error prone. You can always declare a variable in global scope and assign to it later.

Answer (score -2):

You don't a function wrapper for setting a value to a variable.

```
var myRequest = a;
```

That is good enough.

**After thought revision**

in a very basic way a variable can be created on its own like a place holder.

var myRequest;

when you get to the function (say you have a series of functions.

You could do something like this.

function(myRequest=a);

if the function has more than one argument it can look like this.

function(myRequest=a,myConcern=b); as you have it stated in the

var arg1 = 1;
var arg2 = 2;
var arg3 = 3;

ajaxRequest.open(arg1,arg2,arg3);

I hope this is helpful and yes, some more info would help (like the poster below stated).

Comment: `var myRequest = a;` would not have been enough if he needs the data at a later time as it is only visible to the function scope.

Comment: Dinged on before I could revise. Ouch.